# Getting Facebook Events using fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Trying to retrieve facebook events through fql using the query below. I am unable to get venue details other than "id".

fql?q=SELECT name,description, pic_small,pic_big, eid,venue,location from event WHERE eid in (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())

output :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "HappyHour",
      "description": "Let's have fun !!!",
      "pic_small": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yy/r/XcB-JGXohjk.png",
      "pic_big": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yn/r/5uwzdFmIMKQ.png",
      "eid": ......,
      "venue": {
        "id": .......
      },
      "location": "The Crab Pot Seattle"
    }
  ]
}
```

The graph api doc says "The venue where the event being queried is being held. Contains one or more of the following fields: street, city, state, zip, country, latitude, and longitude." but I don't see any of these except venue id.

Do I have to make another request to graph API to get the venue location details? Is there a better way to get the location details in one query itself?

Comment: As what you quoted from the documentation says, one **or** more fields... As far as I know there's no way yo ask for the rest of the fields, you get what fb has.

Comment: Not sure whether facebook is returning me all the data. In the above result the venue id was "113801861983319". If I try http://graph.facebook.com/113801861983319  I see the location details. `code` {
  "id": "113801861983319",
  "name": "The Crab Pot Seattle",
  "website": "www.thecrabpotseattle.com",
  "username": "crabpotseattle",
  "location": {
    "street": "1301 Alaskan Way",
    "city": "Seattle",
    "state": "WA",
    "country": "United States",
    "zip": "98101-2013",
    "latitude": 47.605915163539,
    "longitude": -122.34114741484
  }...
} `code`

Answer (score 6):

You can get the locations for events using [this FQL Multiquery](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3D%7B%22event_info%22%3A%22SELECT%20name%2Cdescription%2C%20pic_small%2Cpic_big%2C%20eid%2Cvenue%2Clocation%20from%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20in%20(SELECT%20eid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me())%22%2C%20%22event_venue%22%3A%22SELECT%20name%2C%20username%2C%20page_id%2C%20location%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20venue.id%20FROM%20%23event_info)%22%7D).

This will get your events and information about their venues. You'll have to write a script on your end to combine them into something usable.

```
fql?q={
 "event_info":
    "SELECT name,description, pic_small,pic_big, eid,venue,location 
      FROM event WHERE eid IN 
         (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())", 
  "event_venue":
     "SELECT name, username, page_id, location 
        FROM page WHERE page_id IN 
          (SELECT venue.id FROM #event_info)"
 }
```

Facebook changed the default encoding for events sometime in April. It used to be that all location data always used to be returned. Since then only the `id` of the location has been returned.

Comment: Thanks. I did endup with the same solution as yours.